# How to override nested "dot" operators?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

If I use `__getattr__` and call `a.b.c` where `a` is an instance of my class, then I get `"b"` inside `__getattr__`, which means I need recursion to override accessing `c` too. But if recursion, I will not know, which call is last, so I will not know, when to return final value, i.e. can't distinguish between `a.b` and `(a.b).c`

How to overcome?

How to get entire chain "b", "c" in overriden operation?

---

For example, A is my class, then suppose I want to be:

```
a = A()

print(a.b)  # prints "hello"
print(a.b.c) # prints "hi"
```

etc.

I.e. I want to override each combination by myself.

Comment: Any concrete example?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the *b* attribute can create an instance of something on the fly:

```py
class A:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "b":
            return B()
        raise AttributeError(name)


class B:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == "c":
            return "hi"
        raise AttributeError(name)


a = A()
print(a.b.c)
# -> "hi"
```

Comment: What about `print(a.b)`? I want it be "hello", not instance of A!

Comment: Thé `print` function uses `__str__`, so you can define this method in `B` class. Can you explain what you really want to do?

Comment: I don't want to limit myself with printing. I need to have specific object at the end of expression and it should not be the same as in the middle.